# Javascript API GET Request fails with code 404. Truncated server response

Tags: javascript, rest, api, google-apps-script, get

I am trying to fetch data via external API using google app script but I keep getting Request failed for **https://api.10000ft.com returned code 404. Truncated server response:**

On debugging, it tells me response not defined. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
function fetchSheet() {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users//time_entries?from=2020-01-06&to=2020-01-14&auth=token');
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: does `api.10000ft.com` allow cross origin requests?

Comment: Hi – Jaromanda X, Yes it does

Comment: What's the truncated server response?

Comment: Is `//` in `users` **`//`** `time` a typo?

Comment: TheMaster here is the response message **Request failed for https://api.10000ft.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: {"message":"not found"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 2, file "GetTimehseets")**

Comment: @TheMaster, the users // was a typo that I have corrected but still getting the same error

Comment: Does curl or postman work? 2. Could you link relevant section of the api  documentation?

Comment: do you know what a 404 error is? since you need to signup or something to that API before you can get in, you have access to documentation that most wont - so read the documentation to see if your URL is valid

Comment: there should be a *valid* userid between the `//` in `users//time_entries`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to send the same request from Postman, and the message I received was "invalid or missing auth token", and not 404.
It seems like you need to add header fields.

You should try something like this (and check where to get the access token from):

```
function fetchSheet(accessToken) {
   var headers = {
      headers: {
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      }
   }
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/time_entries?from=2020-01-06&to=2020-01-14&auth=token', headers);
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Also, the url seems not to fulfil REST's structure: `.../users/HERE_SHOULD_BE_A_USER_ID/time_entries?...`

I guess that your initial mistake with the double slash was that you've missed this path param.

Comment: I also realized that my endpoint were not properly structured. Reused your code with edits and works fine. Thanks